# flask wtform fields access in class methods

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have defined a form like below:

```
class DisForm(FlaskForm):

    dtype = SelectField("dtype", choices=[])
   
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        
        choices = []
        dtypes = DTypes.query.all()
        for t in dtypes:
            item = (t.name, t.title)
            choices.append(item)

        self.dtype.choices = choices # ?????????
```

I want to populate the `choices` of the field in init! How can I do that? using `self.dtype` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this. It seems that is important to call super first in init.

```
class DisForm(FlaskForm):

    dtype = SelectField("dtype", choices=[])
   
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # This is important to call super first
        super(DisForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        choices = []
        dtypes = DTypes.query.all()
        for t in dtypes:
            item = (t.name, t.title)
            choices.append(item)

        self.dtype.choices = choices
```